# Parse Date Time from US Time zone to Datetime.

Tags: c#, vb.net, datetime

How to parse below date time string?

```
2014-01-17T09:59:24.000Z
```

I tried below code but its, not working.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2014-01-17T09:59:24.000Z", "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss %zzzz yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a string like "2014-01-17T09:59:24.000Z"

You can just use `DateTime.Parse("2014-01-17T09:59:24.000Z")`

From [The Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#StringToParse):

*The string to be parsed can take any of the following forms:*

*A string that includes time zone information and conforms to [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). In the following examples, the first string designates Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), and the second string designates the time in a time zone that's seven hours earlier than UTC:*

```
2008-11-01T19:35:00.0000000Z 

2008-11-01T19:35:00.0000000-07:00
```

Answer (score 3):

From [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific
>   format information. **The format of the string representation must match
>   the specified format exactly.**

Clearly your string representation and format is not the same.

You can use it like;

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("2014-01-17T09:59:24.000Z",
                               "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff'Z'", 
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

Output will be;

```
1/17/2014 9:59:24 AM
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/jOw2rW)</kbd>.

For more information, take a look at;

- [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The value you have, `2014-01-17T09:59:24.000Z` is an [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)/[RFC3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) formatted timestamp.  The `Z` at the end is significant, which means that it represents UTC.

You have two options to *correctly* parse it:

- You could parse it to a `DateTime` that has `DateTimeKind.Utc` for it's `.Kind` property:

  ```
  DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2014-01-17T09:59:24.000Z",
                                    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffK",
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                    DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
  ```
- Or, you could parse it to a `DateTimeOffset`, where UTC will correspond to an offset of zero:

  ```
  DateTimeOffset dt = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("2014-01-17T09:59:24.000Z",
                                                "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffK",
                                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  ```

Some of the other answers here are close, but are forgetting to actually consider the `Z` in your string, using the `K` specifier and the `DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind` parameter.  These are important, for without them you will likely end up with a resulting `DateTime` that has `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, which could get treated as *local* time in certain time zone conversion functions.  If you use either of the options I gave you, then the meaning of the `Z` is preserved.